# Page not functioning correctly when opened via Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to keep my pages separately and load them all into one main page using ajax, this way I can change my layouts much quicker. I use Metro UI Css.

Problem is, my page works perfectly when called alone, but when called through ajax and displayed on the main page, it does not respond, or throw any exceptions. This is my html code for the page that is loaded:

```
<head>
    <script src="../../app/webroot/js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../app/webroot/js/jquery/jquery.widget.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../app/webroot/js/prettify/prettify.js"></script>   
    <script src="../../app/webroot/js/load-metro.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="metro">
<div class="accordion" data-role="accordion" style="font-size:20px; color:#3D5168">
    <div class="accordion-frame">
        <a class="heading" href="#"><i class="icon-history"></i>Early days</a>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Line 1</p>   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

I suspect that the line

```
href="#"
```

has something to do with it, it might be trying to call to the original page that it came from, instead of the page it is actually displayed on. I do all the same imports on the "caller" page, and as I said, I get no exceptions.

This is how I load the page (Ajax)

```
function LoadPage(PageName)
    {
        document.getElementById('LoadedPage').style.visibility='hidden';
        document.getElementById('loader').style.visibility='visible'
        var xmlHttp=MakeConn();
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
              if(xmlHttp.readyState === 4)
              {
                HandleLoad(xmlHttp.responseText,PageName);
              }
            };
            xmlHttp.open("GET", "http://www.somewebsite.com/main/"+PageName, true); 
            xmlHttp.send(null);
    }

    function HandleLoad(response,PageName)
    {   
        if(PageName!='home')
        {
            document.getElementById('home').className = 'tile bg-VSblue1';
        }
        if(PageName!='games')
        {
            document.getElementById('games').className = 'tile bg-VSblue1';
        }
        if(PageName!='about')
        {
            document.getElementById('about').className = 'tile bg-VSblue1';
        }
        if(PageName!='contact')
        {
            document.getElementById('contact').className = 'tile bg-VSblue1';
        }
        document.getElementById(PageName).className = 'tile double bg-VSblue1 selected';
        document.getElementById('loader').style.visibility='hidden';
        document.getElementById('LoadedPage').style.visibility='visible';       
        document.getElementById('LoadedPage').innerHTML = response;
    }
```

Does anyone have some suggestion on how to fix this?  Thank you...

Comment: I don't see any javascript or jquery code. How are you loading the pages?

Comment: ^ We have no idea how you're doing this so we can't tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: could you provide the ajax function

Comment: Sorry, I added the ajax function...

Comment: What do you mean by: does not respond?
Is it rendered?
I dont't think this will solve the problem but: If youre including this in an other html file, you can't use the headblock again.

Comment: It is rendered, but when clicking on the object, it is not functioning as it would when opening the page on it's own. I have tried removing the head block, then it was obviously not loading on it's own, but still not functioning as it should..

Answer (score 0):

This happens because after you called AJAX it wasn't initialized so I won't work. To initialize jst add this line after you place the element in body :

```
$.Metro.initAll();
```

That's it now everything will work fine.

Note: If it doesn't try 'initall' instead of 'initAll'